# Upgrade iPad 2 from 4.3.5 to 5.1.1

Tags: itunes, ios, ipad

I want to install iOS 5.1.1 on my iPad 2. Currently it's running on 4.3.5. iTunes just shows me a popup with the option to install iOS 6.0. How can I install 5.1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Unless you already have a copy of the iOS 5.1.1 package for your iPad downloaded, you can only upgrade to the latest supported version for your device.

Answer (score 1):

This is *sometimes* possible. The catch is that iTunes needs to do some sort of authentication with Apple's servers, and historically they only authorize the most recent version for a given device. However I believe there is some overlap after the release of a new version, when the previous version is still valid. Since iOS 6 is relatively new, it's worth a shot at least.

To get the actual file, check [this page](http://www.idownloadblog.com/iphone-downloads/), which lists downloads from Apple.com of previous versions. Note that you need to download the specific file for your device.

Then you can go into iTunes, and **option-click** (shift-click in Windows) the **Update** button for your device. You should get a file dialog, from which you can select the `.ipsw` file you just downloaded. You should then be able to go through the usual updating process, assuming Apple authorizes it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to do that, i've download a legit ipsw file for ios 5.1.1 (ipad 2 gsm) then i tried:
1) Upgrade + Shift, select the ipsw, itunes unpacks the file, and it fails when validating the signature with apple error 3194.
2) DFU Mode, Restore + Shift, select the ipsw, same error (different number) when validating the signature.

I'm really disappointed, i always like to stay behind in upgrades due to bugs and problems. Installing iOS 6 and losing the maps + youtube and more problems with battery and other stuff is not an option, on the other side the current version 4.3.5 does not support the AV Adapter, it seems i'm stuck and i'm not doing nothing wrong.

I've raised a question if it's possible under the apple ios development to upgrade and downgrade ios versions, if it is i'll go with that option, but i'm not sure.

Good Luck

PS: If no solution i'll return my AV Adapter, and definitive i'll look different to apple products, no more iPads, this is not away to treat customers.

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreaking is the way to access and fool with different .ipsws. An iOS device is not a little Mac. Confusing the two leads to misunderstandings, frustration, even heartbreak.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! You can if you're willing to jailbreak!
Upgrade to iOS 6, then downgrade to 5.1.1.

Instructions can be found here: [Downgrade From iOS 6.0 to 5.1.1 without SHSH Blobs](http://ijailbreaknow.com/jailbreak/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-6-to-5.1.1-without-shsh-blobs-saved/)